# Kinect joint coordinates and XNA animation

Tags: xna-4.0, kinect

I have written a program to record the x,y,z coordinated of the Hand joint and I want to animate my models 2D or 3D according to these coordinates. . .However the output of the x,y,z coordinates are fluctuating from -0 to 1 but not more than that..

So i assume I will need to multiply them back with the screen width and height, however it still doesnt seem to animate according to the original x,y,z points

Any transformations I might be missing out?

```
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            position += spriteSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //// TODO: Add your update logic here
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                Viewport view = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
                int maxWidth = view.Width;
                int maxHeight = view.Height;

            //    int i = 0;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {


                    string[] temp = line.Split(',');

                int x = (int) Math.Floor((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) maxWidth);
              int y = (int) Math.Floor((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);



                    motion.Add(new Point(x, y));
            //        Console.WriteLine(temp[0] + "," + temp[1] + "," + motion[i].X+ "," + motion[i].Y);
            //        i++;

                }

            }


//            foreach (Point s in motion)
            {

                position.X = motion[i].X;
                position.Y = motion[i].Y;

            }

  //


            i++;

            a_butterfly_up.Update(gameTime);

            a_butterfly_side.Update(gameTime);

            G_vidPlayer.Play(mossV);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be 0 most of the time, as you cast to int before you multiply (btw. your brackets are somehow messed up anyway).
Maybe try this code instead:

```
   int x = (int) (float.Parse(temp[0])* maxWidth);
   int y = (int) (float.Parse(temp[1]) * maxHeight);
```

Regards!

EDIT:

Your code looks a bit messed up:
At the beginning you use `position += spriteSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;` which make not really sense to me as you overwrite position later on.
I am not able to test much on my current machine, so I will give you a pseudo code snippet of how I would address this problem:

int your objects add:
Vector2D position;
Vector2D target;

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     if position!= target
        position+=target-position*gameTime*speed;
}
```

In the main loop do the following:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Get the target location from your stream
    Set the target of the desired object to the retrieved point
    Update every object
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

This is full pseudo code but might give you a headstart to implement the movement.

Regards!

Comment: I had tried this before but its not correct! Yes i'm sorry for the brackets its supposed to be one less

Comment: Have you tried debugging the values you receive for x and y? Just to make sure the error happens here and not in the animation itself

Comment: yes i have added a breakpoint and the values are fine. . .im guessing there is smth more i have to do before i can get the actually x,y,z values

Comment: Maybe add the animation logic to the topic. If your values are fine, then the error is clearly not rooted in the above snippet

Comment: I have added the logic above. . just changed the x,y param

Comment: I expanded the answer, hope this get you started

Comment: That is what i did as well. .

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for now . .however I dont understand the Why need to multiply or add 0.5f to the maxWidth or maxheight. . .

```
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        string line;
        Viewport view = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
        int maxWidth = view.Width;
        int maxHeight = view.Height;

        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {


            string[] temp = line.Split(',');

            int x = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxWidth);
            int y = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) *maxHeight);


          motion.Add(new Point(x, y));

        }

    }

        position.X = motion_2[i].X;
        position.Y = motion_2[i].Y;
        i++;
```

Comment: I dont think you need to do this. It will stretch your movements in a wrong way. Tryo to multiply y with -1 and keep the 0.5 out of the calculation

Comment: I'll try this .. but what about the Z values ? ? Do i need any transformations for that too

Comment: I just tried it out . . What happens is the if i remove the 0.5f . . the smiley (sprite) just goes out of the screen . .

Comment: int x = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0])*1f) * maxWidth);
            int y = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -1f) *maxHeight); this doesn´t work ?

Comment: I'm sorry to reply after really long . . but 1f doesnt work apparent 0.5f is more accurate somehow . . which doesnt even make sense to me :-/

Comment: Please help me solve this mystery . . cos i need to be able to convert/map the skeletal data into 3D model space coordinates

Comment: Btw the calculation for mapping joints i got it from here:
http://kinectxna.blogspot.com/2012/02/tutorial-5-skeletal-tracking.html

Comment: "It seems very confusing at first but in reality we are doing the same thing for both axis, we are halving the position of the joint adding a 0.5f correction and repositioning it based on the resolution of our program.  This was essentially trial and error to find a method that worked." Its written in the post. The 0.5f is to map it onto screen projection and it was found by trial and error.  So maybe just keep it, or play with the parameter if it isn´t the best for you

Comment: @floatArr the problem is that its not very accurate.. and in my project i need some interaction with the application using joints..for Example play a sound when the skeletal joints (x,y,z) is at the object position (x,y,z) the object can be Texture2D or 3D object

Comment: Maybe i shud start a new thread for that question . . cos this is done